# Install mongo or mongo-org latest version

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, mongodb-query, ubuntu-20.04

I want to install mongo db on my local ubuntu system.
SHould i run
`sudo apt-get install mongodb` or `sudo apt-get install mongodb-org`
And how do i install the latest stable version only of mono db ?

My os version are

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install either the latest stable version of MongoDB or a specific version of MongoDB.

- To install the latest stable version:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

- To install a specific release, you must specify each component package individually along with the version number:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=6.0.2 mongodb-org-database=6.0.2 mongodb-org-server=6.0.2 mongodb-mongosh=6.0.2 mongodb-org-mongos=6.0.2 mongodb-org-tools=6.0.2
```

REF: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/